Movie with character named Toed?
I saw the handle Toed used on the Internet today and I am trying to identify what it refers to, but I cannot recall where I know it from. Does anybody know what movie (or maybe television show) has a character named Toed?
I’m almost certain it is a fantasy genre like Lord of the Rings and the character is a lowly troll-ish type of character. I’m pretty sure (his? his.) name was spelled Toed, but it may have been Tode.
I tried Googling for both but found nothing that fits. Toed just returns sloths, frogs, etc. and Tode returns seemingly random results.

This is not the answer so I'll only comment it; in 2010 there was a television show 'Outsourced' about an American company outsourcing to India. The Indian staff could not be discouraged from mis-pronouncing the boss Todd Dempsy's name as Mr. Toad.

Hehe, yes, I remember that. I liked that show; too bad it was cancelled. :-(

Is it a live-action movie? Do you perhaps have any idea around which year or decade it could've been made?

@poepje, strangely enough, no. All I can recall is his name (which I'm almost positive has an 'E' in it) and a general sense of his character (I'm not even sure about his physical appearance). Unlike most of the other movies and shows, I have little else to go on.

If it's X-Men it is a live-action movie.

@poepje, yes, I'm quite familiar with both the X-Men movies and the definition of "live-action"; thank you. Like I said, I don't remember anything about the context surrounding the character, just a few of his attributes.

It turns out that I was not thinking of a movie at all; the character I was thinking of was named Toede, but he is from the Dragonlance novels.

In X-Men 1 there is a character named Toad.  He's green and has a tongue that stretches quite a ways.  You can find pictures of him on google.

I'm pretty sure it had an 'E', but that definitely looks like it. I'll have to watch the movie again to be sure, but I think you're correct. (I'll look around to see if there is an alternate spelling of the character's name.)

No alternate spelling. Toads are relatives of frogs.  The name (which maybe should have been Frog but I guess it didn't sound evil and menacing enough) comes from the color and the tongue.

@JürgenA.Erhard, yes, I know what a toad is. He is not actually a toad; that’s just a nickname, and names are often modified.

@Beska i'm not seeing what comment you're referring to.  mind joining me in chat?

@Synetech : I'm confused why this answer was accepted, despite being wrong (according to your 8/4/12 comment on your question).

@Beska, the confusion about it being a movie character is most likely caused by the X-Man character than the other ones proposed.

Is this Marvel Universe character the Tode you are looking for?


Thanks but no, it was this one.

Tod (Pronounced tode) - Is the German word for death.
One of the Nazi characters in "Raiders of the Lost Arc" was named Toht.
Names are often very carefully chosen by writers to convey secondary meaning.
(My personal favorite is Blazing saddles "Taggart")
Granted, the user could be using "Toed" to refer to toes.)
Best solution is to ask the user why he picked it.

No, it definitely has nothing to do with toes, that is why Google Images is not helpful because of all the animal results.

in the movie "Soldier", a movie made back in 1998.. the main character's name is Todd.. look for it on Wikipedia, maybe it's what you are looking for.

Todd (3465) from Soldier does not match what I described at all other than having the letters T-O-D in his name. Besides, I already determined that I was thinking of a character from the DragonLance novels.

Maybe you mean Hobgoblin Toede from Dragonlance?
http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Toede

Can you explain your answer? I mean, why you think its matched.
